# Prototype: how to select nested elements?

Tags: javascript, css-selectors, prototypejs

I have follow html structure:

```
<div class="main">
   <ul id="nav">
       <li>
             <a></a>
             <div>
                 <ul class="level0">
                      <li>
                         .......                                
                      </li>
                      .......
                      <li> 
                         .........
                      </li>
                 </ul>
             </div>
       </li>
       ......
       <li>
             <a></a>
             <div>
                 <ul class="level0">
                      <li>
                         .........
                      </li>
                      .........
                      <li> 
                         .........
                      </li>
                 </ul>
             </div>
       </li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

I know how to select all first level li:

```
var listNodeLi = $('#main > ul').childElements();
listNodeLi.each(function(element)
{
     alert(element.nodeName);
});
```

But now for each *element* I have to select another li nodes by select like this:

```
element > div > ul
```

But I cannot understand how to combine *element* and css selectors after I got each *element*?

PS:
So, I've tried that, still didn't work. I got empty list.

```
  var arrLi = $('nav').childElements();
        arrLi.each(function(node)
        {
           list = $(node).down('ul.level0');
           alert(list);
           list.each(function(nodeLi)
           {
              alert(nodeLi.nodeName); 
           });
        });
```

Comment: http://www.prototypejs.org/api/element/down

Comment: Thx, I've tried that and updated question a bit.

Answer (score 1):

If you only want first level `<li>` elements, use:

```
$('.main ul#nav li')
```

If you only want second level `<li>` elements, use:

```
$('.main ul.level0 li')
```

If you want both, you can do:

```
$('.main li').each(function() {
    if($(this).parent().hasClass('level0')) {
        // second level <li>
    }
    else {
        // first level <li>
    }
});
```

Comment: Then I get general LI list. I need to get each Li list (level 2) separately.

Comment: $('.main ul.level0 li') will get you a collection of all second level <li> elements. You can do $('.main ul.level0 li').each(..) to iterate through & process each second level li.

Answer (score 1):

I solved my problem:

```
var arrLi = $('nav').childElements();


    arrLi.each(function(node)
    {
       nodeUl = $(node).select('div > ul.level0');

       if (nodeUl.length > 0)
       {
           /*
           here was a problem because nodeUL has array type here.
           I have only one ul element in the first node, therefore
           call it using nodeUl[0].
           */
           var nodesLi = nodeUl[0].childElements(); 

           nodesLi.each(function(nodeLi)
           {
              alert(nodeLi.nodeName); 
           });
       }
    });
```

Thanks to all for your comments!

Comment: If this is the solution mark it as correct so others can see it clearly.